# intel-xdk html5 platform android aplication working properly in emulator but not working properly in device

Tags: html

I have included a php file using javascript function getApi() it working properly in my intel-xdk emulator but when i load it in to my android device it will not working properly 
so pleas tell me what's wrong with my code , and my device is also connected with internet so it may able to retrive data from the server ,but it can't

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app_framework/css/af.ui.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app_framework/css/icons.min.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index_main.less.css" class="main-less">
  <title>Your New Application</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
  <style type="text/css">
    /* Prevent copy paste for all elements except text fields */
    *  { -webkit-user-select:none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); }
    input, textarea  { -webkit-user-select:text; }
  </style>
  <script src="intelxdk.js">
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    /* This code is used to run as soon as Intel activates */
    var onDeviceReady=function(){
      //hide splash screen
      intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();
    };
    document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready",onDeviceReady,false);
  function getApi() {
                           alert("Yes");
                            $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "http://exam.coreducation.in/api.php",
    success: function(data){
var total = "";
var record = JSON.parse( data );
for(i=0; i<record.length; i++){
total += ("Contact: "+record[i]['contact']+", Name: "+record[i]['name']+", City: "+record[i]['city'] + "<br/>");
}
$('#ddata').html("<h4 style='text-align:center'>"+total+"</h4>")
    }
  });
}    
    </script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="app_framework/appframework.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="app_framework/appframework.ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="afui">

  <!-- content goes here-->
  <div class="uwrap" id="content">
    <div class="upage panel" id="page0" data-header="none" data-footer="none">
      <div class="upage-outer">
        <div class="upage-content">

          <div class="grid grid-pad urow uib_row_1 row-height-1" data-uib="layout/row">
            <div class="col uib_col_1 col-0_12-12" data-uib="layout/col">
              <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">

                <a class="button widget uib_w_1 d-margins icon graph" data-uib="app_framework/button" onclick="return getApi();">GetApiData</a><span class="uib_shim">
                  </span>
            <div id="ddata">DAta Will Show Here</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="uib_shim"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /upage-content -->

      </div>
      <!-- /upage-outer -->

    </div>


  </div>
  <!-- /uwrap -->
</body>

</html>`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The api is blocked due to Cross domain access, same reason why your code will not work in any browser. But there is a way to make it work in Intel XDK apps, just add `<script src="xhr.js"></script>` after your intelxdk.js script inclusion. It will then work on device.

More info about AJAX and XDK here: http://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/how-to-access-JSON-data-in-HTML5-apps

Answer (score 0):

I resolved similar problem using [domain whitelistening](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html).

In Intel XDK it can be done by following next steps:

Open Projects Tab

Expand Build Settings

Enter "*" (without quotes) to Domain List field.