# Intel xdk function (cookie) works fine in emulator, but doesnt work in device even i have put <script src="intelxdk.js"></script> tag in index.html

Tags: javascript, android, html, cookies, intel-xdk

I am trying to test cookie in device, so i build a simple application. 
I have tested it on emulator and works fine. 
but when i test it in apps testing server, and in device, All the Intel xdk  function doesnt work 
(I just want test cookie), 
I have put script <script>src="intelxdk.js"</script> in index.html.
But it doesnt work also, i have searched here,
[intel-xdk html5 platform android aplication working properly in emulator but not working properly in device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161652/intel-xdk-html5-platform-android-aplication-working-properly-in-emulator-but-not) , so i include the <script src="xhr.js"></script> but it doesnt work also

My code is:
(Sorry, im just new here and cant post image if post under 10. Here the image)
http://helpmedong.esy.es/

The alert is still :  Intel is not defined..
thx before..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ive found the problem. 
I click "Project" button => 
then click +plugin tab => 
featured and custome cordova plugins => 
 
check the cache option.
Thx everyone.

And then put the coding in deviceready.

Comment: If not has "plugin tab" you need Upgrade yout project to Cordoba click em Project-Type: Upgrade,

Thanks. Work for me

Answer (score 0):

About my comment above and with cheyong help, I go to this way...

If you begin with project withou Cordova you click second option
[image: project type]

But, in this way haven't plugins choice:

[image: project option]

[image: Project Type withou Cordova]

Than upgrade...
Note the option "plugins"

[image: upgrade]
[image: now show plugin option]